# H2 Spring Boot - not creating tables with LocalDateTime properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I have Spring Boot 3.2 with H2 for development. H2 is creating some tables but not all.

I was initially developing my project with MySQL database - but then created a new profile for development in Spring Boot and changed the database to H2 in mem.

It was at this point that some entities do not get tables created in the H2 database.

For example:

**HealthCheck**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitalizer", "handler"})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "health_check_seq", sequenceName = "HEALTH_CHECK_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 50)
@Table(name = "health_check")
public class HealthCheck {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "health_check_seq")
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Bird bird;
   
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "healthCheck")
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime catchDateTime;


    @JsonBackReference
    private Point<G2D> location;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "holder_id")
    private User holder;
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/IdeaProjects/test/h2mem/data;MV_STORE=false;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:/datadev.sql
```

Updated app.props:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST_SCHEMA_NAME
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I have tried inserting data in the datadev.sql but it fails because the `HEALTH_CHECK` table does not exist.

**StackTrace (snippet)**

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "
CREATE TABLE HEALTH_CHECK (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CATCH_DATE_TIME DATETIME([*]6),
    LOCATION GEOMETRY,
    RELEASE_DATE_TIME DATETIME(6),
    BIRD_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    HOLDER_ID BIGINT,
    MEASURER_ID BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB "; expected "FOR, UNSIGNED, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:

create table health_check (
    id bigint not null,
    catch_date_time datetime(6),
    location geometry,
    release_date_time datetime(6),
    bird_id bigint not null,
    holder_id bigint,
    measurer_id bigint,
    primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB [42001-197]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:217)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:555)
at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:3518)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfMore(Parser.java:950)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:6571)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4615)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:380)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:311)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:217)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:78)
... 41 common frames omitted
2023-09-09 08:47:22 -
```

**Update**

On the stack trace I have a few lines that reference `InnoDB` which I believe is what MySQL uses.

```
   ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "\000d\000a    create table bird (\000d\000a
```

Despite commenting out every reference to MySQL in build.gradle and making sure no reference to it in my application-mem-db.properties I am still seeing it on the standard out (and tables not created accordingly)

How can I get H2 to create tables for all entities?

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back, and had to add the dialect for it to work, try it and if does work I will add an answer: `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` this to verify the script being created (helped to identify the problem) and this `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and this one to set compatibility.

Comment: Add `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and this one to ? `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.` ?

Comment: Yes both, the first one is just to check what is the sql script the application is trying to use to create the tables, the second one is to set the hibernate dialect to be MySQL compatible. In my case, some of the annotations contained mysql specific database stuff which H2 didn't support once I added the dialect the problem went away

Comment: Thanks - just tried but still table not found.

Comment: Is there a way to see there DDL (and errors) generated by Hibnerante?

Comment: yeap you can set the application to print the sql in the logs `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

Comment: Also your question might be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45302132/460557 check if anything there might help

Comment: No I think he had connection issues. I can paste stack trace in chat (see comments below)

Comment: Add to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255216/discussion-between-al-grant-and-jorge-campos).

Comment: based on your exception the problem is H2 doesn't have `DATETIME` type... http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html

Comment: I will suggest running a local client of H2 and trying the DDL script there, see what is wrong, then search around how to workaround the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the resource that you provided, your code appears to be correct. I think the issue might be in the application.properties file. Please ensure that you have the following properties set:"

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

update class with

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "health_check")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Data
public class HealthCheck {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "health_check_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "health_check_seq", sequenceName = "HEALTH_CHECK_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 50)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bird_id") // Make sure to specify the correct column name
    private Bird bird;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "healthCheck")
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime catchDateTime;

    @JsonBackReference
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point, 4326)") // Customize this based on your database and GIS library
    private Point location;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "holder_id")
    private User holder;

    // Getter and setter methods for all fields
}
```

Comment: Updated to include a very simply application.properties - still no HealthCheck table. I need to use h2 on disk so I can see tables created.

Comment: You can add `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
`

Comment: Also, please try the updated class that I provided in the previous answer

Comment: Those update properties fixed one class but sigh now I get Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "DATA" not found; SQL statement:

Comment: It looks like the LocalDateTime is causing the issue - if I remove private LocalDateTime releaseDateTime; it creates the table. I dont know why or what the fix is tho.

Comment: LocalTime on its own is ok, LocalDate on its own is ok - table is created.

Comment: Could You share with me, application.properties or update the spring.datasource.url to ```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255215/discussion-between-al-grant-and-magic-developement).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had a few issues that were stopping my H2 database from building tables.

**Problem 1**

The first issue with it not creating any tables where I had a `LocalDateTime` property - this was because despite using Spring Boot 3.2 I had a legacy reference in my `build.gradle` which meant I was using a very old version of H2.

I removed:

```
ext['h2.version'] = '1.4.197'
```

And let Spring Boot set the H2 version (much newer).

**Problem 2**

For the sake of completeness I will add that I still could not get my tables built with H2.

A secondary issue I suspect was a table named with the reserved word `user` - I renamed this to `Person` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290609/what-is-the-best-practice-in-naming-your-user-table) answer.

**Problem 3**

The final issue was not realising that `application.properties` gets loaded on all profiles so it was loaded in **addition** to my `application-dev.properties` - this meant I had the MySQL Engine=InnoDB loaded and H2 was getting confused when trying to create the tables.